# Struggling to have DayJs available for all tests in cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, dayjs

I'm currently starting a new Cypress project, the application to test is quite "calendar centered" and I'll have to play a lot with dates.

My issue is I can't get DayJs available for the whole project without having to import it in every spec files.

For instance, in a test.spec.ts, this is working

```
import dayjs = require('dayjs');
    
describe('Some suite', () => {       
   it('Some Test', () => {
      // some stuff
      const myDate = dayjs('11-11-2022', 'dd-MM-YYYY' );
      // other stuff
   })
})
```

But when I do this in support/index.ts

```
import dayjs = require('dayjs')
    
declare namespace Cypress {        
    interface Cypress {
        dayjs: dayjs.Dayjs;
    }
}
```

and then this in my spec

```
describe('Some suite', () => {       
    it('Some Test', () => {
       // some stuff
       const myDate = Cypress.dayjs('11-11-2022', 'dd-MM-YYYY' );
       // other stuff
    })
})
```

it says

> Cypress.dayjs is not a function

Any idea on how I could get this work?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/cypress/support/index.ts`, add dayjs to the global Cypress (just like momentjs used to be included).

**/cypress/support/index.ts**

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs')

declare namespace Cypress {        
  interface Cypress {
    dayjs: dayjs.Dayjs;
  }
}

Cypress.dayjs = dayjs
```

Now `const myDate = Cypress.dayjs('11-11-2022', 'dd-MM-YYYY')` should work.

Comment: Woow! I thought that only namespace/interface was sufficient! Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an update now that there is no index.ts in supper? I understand the config file setup for Cypress has been updated.

Comment: We're not actually talking about the config file here, but you can discover the details of that [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration).

Comment: The questioner uses/used `/cypress/support/index.ts` - the default file is `/cypress/support/e2e.ts`, but you're not locked in to that naming. (See aforementioned document).